# Restrict access to public URL many times

Tags: access-control, ddos, denial-of-service, url, spring-framework

I have such situation. Imagine there is a public service (URL). What we don't want, is for someone, to be able to access this URL many times in short period of time, because they will be able to block our database (essentially a DDOS attack, I presume?).

Is there a way to effectively protect against this type of attack? Technology we use is Spring Security (java).

Comment: I'd agree of DoS here. DDoS implies there is a network of machines trying to access your servers to saturate the access.

Answer (score 3):

1. you can try implementing **[Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927984/throttling-a-rest-api-in-java)**  in your code.
2. You can also use a Proxy Firewall or LoadBalancer to limit the rate of requests.

   - There are open-source proxies like HAProxy and Nginx which can be used.
   - there are also factory made proxy firewalls available.
3. There are Cloud Proxies like Cloudflare which can be used.(my money is on these)
4. If you are running your Web Application in a Public Cloud, your cloud provider may also provide some security [measures](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) .
5. some kind of Caching may also help, depending on the scenario. refer [HTTP-Caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

Comment: Some kind of cache might also help?